# Spring DBCP connection pooling | configuring the retry count

Tags: java, spring, connection-pooling, apache-commons-dbcp

Is there any way to specify the 'retry' count in Spring - DBCP connection pooling?

If the connection is not obtained for the first time, I want to try it atleast 3 times.

Answer (score 1):

One of the approach

write an spring aop aspect which will catch such transient DB related exceptions and retry for pre-configured number of times.
Apply this aspect on methods.

Comment: If you only want to catch connection failures, you should catch DataAccessResourceFailureException. Catching all exceptions means you would retry failed SQL too. Depends on what the OP needs.

Answer (score 1):

BasicDataSource has a handful of methods that are protected and exist so subclasses can make their own implementation changes. One of these methods is createConnectionFactory() which creates a simple object to do the underlying connection to the driver. You can override that to point to your own connection retry logic.